# How to add details without ruining the current curvature/form of the mesh?

Tags: modeling

So, I'm trying to cut some circular holes in the mesh, but by doing so I'll have to add some more loop cuts which will ruin the curvature when subdivided. Is there a way to fix this without manually moving/ edge sliding all the vertices?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible, except probably with some hardsurface addons? you could also use a subdivided version of your cylinder to help to snap to the right position but it's a bit tedious...